# Not able to update the button text when pyqt connect signal run the function

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Here not able to set the text in button. If I don't call the external function then it updates the text but I don't want that.

I want to run the function and then update the button text. Can someone tell me how to update the button text when the signal is running the function?

It updates in the end not while running.

EDIT: I have added the external function that data from the uart.

```
def uart1_serial_read():
    device = serial.Serial(uart1, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1,
            timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
    print('UART1: %s ' % device.name)
    run = True
    while run:
            #print (ser.readline())
            data=device.readline()
            print(data)

            if (data == TEST_END):
                print("TEST DONE *****")
                run = False

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    # I setup my gui function geometry size,
    #def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    def retranslateUi:
      self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.run_iot_uart1)

  def signal_uart1(self, MainWindow):
      print("Calling signal here")
      _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
      # set this button to test once its done
      self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Running"))
      # This text doesn't update my button anyone can tell me why?
      self.pushButton_83.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Running"))
      print("Green")

  def run_iot_uart1(self, MainWindow):
      _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
      self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "start"))
      #calling external function
      uart1_serial_read()
      self.signal_uart1(MainWindow)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I do not understand what is not being updated?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.run_iot_uart1)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 100, 50))

        self.pushButton_83 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_83.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 50, 100, 50))


        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button_1"))


    def signal_uart1(self, MainWindow):
        print("Calling signal here")
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        # set this button to test once its done
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Running"))
        # This text doesn't update my button anyone can tell me why?
        self.pushButton_83.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Running"))
        print("Green")

    def run_iot_uart1(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "start")) # ???
        #calling external function
        self.signal_uart1(MainWindow)


class MainView(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainView()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that reTranslateUi is being called and being called correctly? Also the retranslateUi method is indented further than the rest of the code. Can you provide the whole Ui_MainWindow class?

Comment: Well, obviously I am aware of the class call. The code I posted is a minimal example of the problem. I don't have any problem in running the script, the issue is updating the button text when the signal slot is running.

Comment: I figured you were aware of the class call, but asked anyways. However right now there isn't enough code to go off of. If it is updating in the end and not as soon as the button is pressed then it sounds like it's getting blocked or something. If you provide more code I'll do what I can for you.

Comment: ok. I will add the minimal running code. True, my external function is serial read from uart.

Comment: I appreciate it. I do believe it is getting blocked somewhere, and the only reason I say that is I made a simple test and just setting the text on the button should be enough.

Comment: I think I see what you are wanting. Hit the start button, change to running, when done change back to start?
If that is what you are doing then you just need to have a completed signal emit when your method is done running that the main window object will connect to and run a method to set text back to start. I would also just preset the text to start on the buttons as well.